# How smart is GBoard keyboard's Predictive Suggestions bar?

Tags: natural-language, onscreen-keyboard, predictive-text

When typing texts on my Android phone the suggestion bar always shows 3 possible 'words'. Often the suggestions are good, but could be a lot better if the algorithm simply took in to account parts of speech, plural and other things from the previous words of a sentence. It is annoying to have to type many letters to get the plural form of a word to show, or to get the 'ion' form when the previous words practically demand that it be the only choice. Does the keyboard prediction include any of that? (Getting it to work for 100 languages, as Gboard is said to support, would be a lot of effort.)

A flaw is that inexplicably my keyboard suggests choices like 'se' and 'SE' *a lot* when I am just trying to type a word like 'set' for example. Why the stupid suggestions? Predictions are supposed to be based on previous usage, but I don't type non-words very often. This is another example of not predicting a sensible choice of next word.

So, my question is: does or could the algorithm actually interpret the previous words in a sentence at all when making suggestions? Does it depend on whether my phone has 'data' turned on or not? (Usually it is off.)

Comment: This chap ran a packet sniffer (on iOS) and it seems like it doesn't connect to the internet http://www.macworld.com/article/3070767/ios/googles-gboard-doesnt-send-your-keystrokes-but-it-does-leak-chicken-and-noodles.html

Comment: We could add a few bits to the dictionary: part of speech and plural. Tiny increase in size, massive increase in usability.